# joomla set JTable property to null

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

How i can set JTable property too null and save it 
my code so far w/o succes:

```
$table = JTable::getInstance($type='detalegrupy', $prefix='FootsalTable', $config = array());
$table->load($id);
$table->promotion = NULL;
$id_group = $table->id_group;
$table->store();
```

or how to restore it to it's default value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i found answer for it,

```
$table->store(TRUE);
```

done the work.
sorry for spam

Answer (score 1):

Edit the file `administrator/components/YOUR_COMPONENT/tables/NAME_OF_YOUR_TABLE.php` and add this function inside the table class:

```
public function store($updateNulls = true)
{
    return parent::store($updateNulls);
}
```